# Rest api filtering in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

I have a project in spring boot, in my controller I have many methods with similar functionality.

Methods for searching post, popular, latest etc and the urls with slight variation like -

url 1 - search/{topicId}

url 2 - search/popular/{topicId}

url 3 - search/latest/{topicId}

What I want, is to have a single method with filter in url like search/{topicId}?filter=popular

How to achieve this in spring boot?

Comment: Use a [RequestParam](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
OOPs... it does not depend on SpringBoot. It is simply a URL mapping...You can accept the type as a request param and can process as per business.....

@Controller
public class BookController {

        @GetMapping(value = "/search/{topicId}")
        @ResponseBody
        public List<Object> getBooksByType(@RequestParam String type) {
            try{
                if("popular".equalsIgnoreCase(type)){
                    //do your business stuffs                   
                }else if ("latest".equalsIgnoreCase(type)){
                    //do your business stuffs
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return new ArrayList<>();

        }
}
```